# Calculating distance between point (address) and every road in city using QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance, proximity

I'm new on QGIS, and I'm trying to measure the distance between an address and every road in the city.

I used NNjoin but I got only the shortest distance between the address and the nearest road.

Is there a package or plug-in that I can use to calculate a distance between the address and all roads in the city?

Answer (score 1):

As you have already tried NNjoin plugin, I assume you have a point layer which represents the address.

(1) Open the attribute table of your road (line) layer and start the Field Calculator.

(2) Replace `'point'` of the syntax below by your actual point layername and run:

```
length(shortest_line($geometry, geometry(get_feature_by_id('point', '1'))))
```

---

If you also want to output the `"shortest line"` (a new line layer), use the `Geometry by expression` tool:

```
shortest_line($geometry, geometry(get_feature_by_id('point', '1')))
```

Comment: I tried this approach but it does not work. it doesn't give an error message through

Comment: @Mr.F Please double check your point layername and the id of the point.